# sh file installation (CMake package)

Tags: software-installation, filesystem, cmake

newbie's question : I need to install latest cmake on my ubuntu.
I've downloaded .sh file
allowed this to execute as a program and run.
seems it was not a fully functional setup but an archive only instead.
so it was unpacked into my home:
/home//Downloads/cmake/*
looks like I have to perform a lot of manual work :(

I suppose that best place would be /opt/cmake/
and I also need to include its /bin/ into pathes for search.
to run this from any file system place

could you explain me how I can do this? or (preferable) does correct setup exist which performs real installation?

rgds

Comment: Try this PPA instead: https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/ubuntu/cmake-3.x